# How do I move items with an expanded collapsed menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I expand a collapsed menu the items below it don't move and the expanded menu overlaps the items. How do I get rid of this feature? What I want to happen is the item below (in this case "Zelda Playlist") to go down with the expanded collapse and return back to its original place when the menu is collapsed. Would it be through CSS or JavaScript? Also I recommend expanding the snippet so you can understand what I mean better.

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("pgsearchbar").value;
  filter = input.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("searchitems");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    finder = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    letter = finder.textContent || finder.innerText;
    if (input.length === 0 || letter.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
  }
}

function PlaySound(soundObj) {
  var audio = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url("sky.jpg");
  padding: 60px;
  color: lightblue;
}

.banntxt {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-family: "Faster One";
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Faster One";
  font-size: 25px;
}

li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

#searchitems li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#searchitems {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 11px;
}

#searchitems li a {
  display: block;
  color: #4a9cb5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 5%;
}

#searchitems li a:hover {
  color: #5cbaff;
}

#searchbtn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.collapsibleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  top: 34%;
}

.collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
  max-width: 80px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.collapse,
.collapsing {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="banntxt">abcdefghijklmnop</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">ABC</span>
      <h2 style="font-size:26px;">Contact us at: abcdefgh@gmail.com | ###-####-####</h2>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul id="navbaritems" class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">About me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Blah</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <input id="pgsearchbar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                <button id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin:5px;" type="submit">Search</button>
            <ul id="searchitems">
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page3.html">Page4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsibleWrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                Zelda Playlist
            </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                        Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: relative` instead of `absolute` on the `.collapsibleWrapper` element. Reposition as necessary

```
.collapsibleWrapper {
    position: relative;
    right: 3%;
    top: 34%;
}
```

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("pgsearchbar").value;
  filter = input.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("searchitems");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    finder = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    letter = finder.textContent || finder.innerText;
    if (input.length === 0 || letter.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
  }
}

function PlaySound(soundObj) {
  var audio = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url("sky.jpg");
  padding: 60px;
  color: lightblue;
}

.banntxt {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-family: "Faster One";
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Faster One";
  font-size: 25px;
}

li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

#searchitems li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#searchitems {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 11px;
}

#searchitems li a {
  display: block;
  color: #4a9cb5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 5%;
}

#searchitems li a:hover {
  color: #5cbaff;
}

#searchbtn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.collapsibleWrapper {
  position: relative;
  right: 3%;
  top: 34%;
}

.collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
  max-width: 80px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.collapse,
.collapsing {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="banner">
      <h1 class="banntxt">abcdefghijklmnop</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">ABC</span>
      <h2 style="font-size:26px;">Contact us at: abcdefgh@gmail.com | ###-####-####</h2>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul id="navbaritems" class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">About me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Blah</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <input id="pgsearchbar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                <button id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin:5px;" type="submit">Search</button>
            <ul id="searchitems">
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="page3.html">Page4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsibleWrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                Zelda Playlist
            </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                        Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                    </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <audio controls>
                                        <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                    </audio>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
        <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
            <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`position: absolute` as described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
> determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Comment: When I change position to relative, the left and top functions dont work. It actually messes up everything else about the collapse menu (width of menu, location, keeping the button and menu together).

Comment: ^^ For example, trying to change the top or bottom positioning just doesnt work. And the menu is on the opposite side of the website.

Comment: it is positioned according to the normal flow of the document now since it is of `position: relative;` therefore, like I indicated in my answer, repositioning should occur. for example since this is a `div` element, try using `margin-left: auto;` to place back the button to the right. here is some example css to get you started `.collapsibleWrapper { position: relative; right: 3%; top: 34%; max-width: 28%; margin-left: auto; }`

Comment: `top` just doesn't work at all for some reason. Is that expected? The rest of it works and I even got the menu to stick with the button. Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using static measurements such as `px` for your `top` property in this situation. If you opt to use `%` measurements, you need to define a `height` for the `.collapsibleWrapper`'s container, which at this point is `body`. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#Values) regarding `percentage` values for CSS `top`. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check it.

You should use `position:relative` if you want to reserve the space on the interface.

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("pgsearchbar").value;
  filter = input.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("searchitems");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    finder = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    letter = finder.textContent || finder.innerText;
    if (input.length === 0 || letter.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
  }
}

function PlaySound(soundObj) {
  var audio = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url("sky.jpg");
  padding: 60px;
  color: lightblue;
}

.banntxt {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-family: "Faster One";
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Faster One";
  font-size: 25px;
}

li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

#searchitems li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#searchitems {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 11px;
}

#searchitems li a {
  display: block;
  color: #4a9cb5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 5%;
}

#searchitems li a:hover {
  color: #5cbaff;
}

#searchbtn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.collapsibleWrapper {
  position: relative; 
}

.collapsibleWrapper .btn-primary {
  max-width: 80px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.collapse,
.collapsing {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster One">
  <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div>
            <div class="banner">
                <h1 class="banntxt">abcdefghijklmnop</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="collapsibleWrapper">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Zelda Playlist
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="width:28%;">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" style="text-align:center">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            Dragon Roost Island - Wind Waker
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                                        <audio controls>
                                            <source src="dragonroost.mp3">
                                        </audio>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo" style="text-align:center">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            Gerudo Valley - Ocarina of Time
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                                        <audio controls>
                                            <source src="gerudo.mp3">
                                        </audio>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" style="width:99%;">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree" style="text-align:center">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary text-center collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                            Lost Woods - Ocarina of Time
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                                        <audio controls>
                                            <source src="lostwoods.mp3">
                                        </audio>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">ABC</span>
                <h2 style="font-size:26px;">Contact us at: abcdefgh@gmail.com | ###-####-####</h2>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul id="navbaritems" class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">About me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button onclick="window.location.href='#';" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Blah</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <input id="pgsearchbar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                <button id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin:5px;" type="submit">Search</button>
                                <ul id="searchitems">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">About Me</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="page3.html">Page4</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
        <audio src="coin.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="coin" enablejavascript="true">
            <audio src="death.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="death" enablejavascript="true">
                <script>
                var death = document.getElementById("death");
                death.volume = 0.2;
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```